# vbscript compare last value to new

Tags: vbscript

I have a 4 digit field that is constantly renewd and value changes. I need to print the field if the value in the field has changed more then 4 digits.
Example:
field_value=0111
if field_value=0112 (does not print)
if field_value=0116 (prints the value)

Comment: Hi Im sorry my explenation was a little messy.
The value comes from a scale and it can vary up and down.

Answer (score 0):

As I don't understand your spec - what exactly are your data and how do you measure the difference? - all I can give you is:

```
Option Explicit

Dim o : o = -1 ' definitely out of range
Dim n
For Each n In Split("0111 0112 0116 9990 9991 9995 9996")
    n = CLng(n)
    If 4 <= n - o Then
       WScript.Echo o, n, "yes"
       o = n ' <-- the important part
    Else
       WScript.Echo o, n, "no"
    End If
Next
```

output:

```
cscript 25442674.vbs
-1 111 yes
111 112 no
111 116 yes
116 9990 yes
9990 9991 no
9990 9995 yes
9995 9996 no
```

If you can't specify the first out of range value or need to treat the first differently, you must use a counted loop.

Comment: I wonder if his `field_value` can decrease? He just says _change_. You may need to use `4 <= Abs(n - o)`.